# Can we call Http POST service call using App_Initializer?

Tags: angular

If I call Http post service call during App Initialization that works fine, however on page refresh that call gets triggered and which is not required as it is a POST call. How can we prevent it being called on refresh?

Comment: When you refresh the page the app is re-initialised, so that request *should* be made again.

Answer (score -1):

Whatever you have written within the constructor will be executed at the beginning of the app.If you want to prevent a particular function from executing,You can write one function and give condition for being execute.

```
constructor() {
   this.i=this.getStatus();
   this.executeByCondition( this.i);
 }
 getStatus() { 
   return status;
 }
 executeByCondition(i) {
   if(i==true) {
    //You can do whatever thing  you want to do
 }
 }
```